# How to switch the video's quality in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was wondering how Youtube/Netflix was switching (for example) between  360p and 480p...

Is it only on setup and user action ? or they can switch in live (without cut) ? but how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) which uses HTML5 Media Source Extensions ([MSE](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)) to manage adaptive bitrate streaming playback. MSE allows you a lot more control of what is being fed into the media element buffer than just using the `<video>` tag.

In this scenario you will be able to make decisions every time you need to get the next chunk to populate the buffer if you want to do it at the current bitrate or switch to a higher (or lower) bitrate to trade off quality vs buffering